# Expected value of $X^2$

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a normally distributed random variable with $\mu = 4$ and $\sigma = 2$. If $E[X]$ denotes the expectation of $X$, then what is the value of $E[X^2]$?

So I don't know exactly how to obtain the expected value of a normal distribution, let alone how to obtain $E[X^2]$. Some hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: What is the definition of variance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, by definition of the variance, we have
$$
E[X^2]=\mathrm{Var}(X)+E[X]^2.
$$
Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 3):

If $E[X]=\mu$ and $E[(X-\mu)^2]=\sigma^2$ then

\begin{eqnarray}
E[X^2] &=& E[X-\mu+\mu]^2\\
       &=& E[(X-\mu)^2]-2E[(X-\mu)\mu]+E[\mu^2]\\
       &=&\sigma^2-2\mu E[X-\mu]+\mu^2\\
       &=& \sigma^2+\mu^2
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: very nice, (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Think about connecting variance with $E[X^2]$ and $E[X]$